# Proving that a sequence defined by $a_{n+1}=e^{a_n}-1$ converges to finite number or infinity

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

> Suppose $a_1>0$ and $(a_n)$ is defined by the following expression:
>
> $$a_{n+1}=e^{a_n}-1,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$
>
> Prove that $(a_n)$ either converges to a finite limit or $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=\pm \infty$ and find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$

Proof: it is easy to show that $e^x>x+1$ for all $x>0$. I also proved that $a_n>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and that $(a_n)$ is increasing. This already means that $(a_n)$ either converges to a finite limit or $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=\pm \infty$. Now suppose $(a_n)$ is bounded. Then $(a_n)$ converges and $L:=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=\sup \{a_n | n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Because $e^x$ is continuous everywhere, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}=e^{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n}-1$ or $L=e^L-1$. It is easy to see that $L=0$ is the only solution. Thus $\sup \{a_n | n\in\mathbb{N}\}=0$ which contradicts the fact that $a_1>0$. So $(a_n)$ is not bounded, and because it is increasing $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n= \infty$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

$a_{n+1}
=e^{a_n}-1
\ge (1+a_n+a_n^2/2)-1
=a_n(1+a_n/2)
$.
Therefore
$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
> 1+a_n/2
$.
Therefore,
for any $k$,
$\frac{a_{n+k+1}}{a_{n+k}}
> 1+a_{n+k}/2
> 1+a_{n}/2
$
since
$a_n$ is increasing.

Multiplying these,
$\frac{a_{n+k}}{a_{n}}
> (1+a_{n}/2)^k
> 1+ka_n/2
$
which shows the
divergence.